# confusion when using radio boxes in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code in c# which uses visual components.

I have some radio in a groupeBox.

how can I make a CheckedChanged event for this groupeBox.

I usually make event for buttons by clicking though I can't make CheckChanged event by cliking the groupeBox; it makes a click event or Enter event.

I added my Instructor's code too.

```
// Using RadioButtons to set message window options.
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RadioButtonTest
{
    // Form contains several RadioButtons--user chooses one
    // from each group to create a custom MessageBox
    public partial class RadioButtonTestForm : Form
    {
      // create variables that store the user's choice of options
      private MessageBoxIcon iconType;
      private MessageBoxButtons buttonType;

      // default constructor
      public RadioButtonTestForm()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      } // end constructor

      // change Buttons based on option chosen by sender
      private void buttonType_CheckedChanged( 
         object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
         if ( sender == okRadioButton ) // display OK Button
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.OK;

         // display OK and Cancel Buttons
         else if ( sender == okCancelRadioButton )
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;

         // display Abort, Retry and Ignore Buttons
         else if ( sender == abortRetryIgnoreRadioButton )
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore;

         // display Yes, No and Cancel Buttons
         else if ( sender == yesNoCancelRadioButton )
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel;

         // display Yes and No Buttons
         else if ( sender == yesNoRadioButton )
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;

         // only on option left--display Retry and Cancel Buttons
         else
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel;
      } // end method buttonType_Changed

      // change Icon based on option chosen by sender
      private void iconType_CheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
         if ( sender == asteriskRadioButton ) // display asterisk Icon
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk;

         // display error Icon
         else if ( sender == errorRadioButton )
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Error;

         // display exclamation point Icon
         else if ( sender == exclamationRadioButton )
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation;

         // display hand Icon
         else if ( sender == handRadioButton )
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Hand;

         // display information Icon
         else if ( sender == informationRadioButton )
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Information;

         // display question mark Icon
         else if ( sender == questionRadioButton )
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Question;

         // display stop Icon
         else if ( sender == stopRadioButton )
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Stop;

         // only one option left--display warning Icon
         else
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Warning;
      } // end method iconType_CheckChanged

      // display MessageBox and Button user pressed
      private void displayButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
         // display MessageBox and store
         // the value of the Button that was pressed
         DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
            "This is your Custom MessageBox.", "Custom MessageBox",
            buttonType, iconType);

         // check to see which Button was pressed in the MessageBox
         // change text displayed accordingly
         switch ( result )
         {
            case DialogResult.OK:
               displayLabel.Text = "OK was pressed.";
               break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
               displayLabel.Text = "Cancel was pressed.";
               break;
            case DialogResult.Abort:
               displayLabel.Text = "Abort was pressed.";
               break;
            case DialogResult.Retry:
               displayLabel.Text = "Retry was pressed.";
               break;
            case DialogResult.Ignore:
               displayLabel.Text = "Ignore was pressed.";
               break;
            case DialogResult.Yes:
               displayLabel.Text = "Yes was pressed.";
               break;
            case DialogResult.No:
               displayLabel.Text = "No was pressed.";
               break;
         } // end switch
      }

      private void RadioButtonTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void buttonTypeGroupBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void iconTypeGroupBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      } // end method displayButton_Click
   } // end class RadioButtonsTestForm
} // end namespace RadioButtonsTest
```

Comment: Basic 101 on `How to work with my tools of the trade`. Right Click over the radiobutton. Select Properties, Select the Event Window (The Lightning Icon in the Properties window) Search for the CheckedChanged event and double click on it....

Comment: my problem is this that I think all of the components which are added to a groupBox will be a part of that groupBox. now I want to have CheckedChanged for the GroupBox not for a radio button. can you say how?!

Comment: @MediaDepp There is **NO** CheckedChanged EventHandler for your GroupBox it is on the RadioButtons as everyone else has stated. When you place items in a container the container does not inherit the events of the contained items.

Answer (score 2):

The `CheckedChanged` event is on the radio buttons, not on the group box. But what you can do, is to point all the radio buttons to the same handler. If you go to the event list in the properties window, there's a small lightning icon. Click that and you'll get a list of all the events where you'll be able to pick the same handler for all of them.

Comment: then you might want to consider marking this as the correct answer